# Adding new methods to the Apache mahout

Tags: java, mahout, mahout-recommender

I am trying to do some work and research on recommender systems. I want to use Apache Mahout. However, I want to add some methods as there is no implementations for them now. I tried to do that but the source code of Mahout is locked and I cannot add or change anything. I'm wondering if anyone knows how to resolve this issue.

Comment: It's an open source project. You can download source from Github (https://github.com/apache/mahout). You can edit any files in a text editor. Which file and method is giving you a problem?

Comment: I use Intellij as my IDE. For example I want to add a method RecommendUsers(itme i) to the recommender object. I want this method to return the users that are interested in item i.

Comment: Then you're not actually going to modify Mahout source, you're just going to write an application that uses Mahout to produce a recommendation. Several tutorials exists on YouTube right now that demonstrate such systems.

Comment: This is not an answer. Several videos exist on somewhere is not a scientific answer to my question. at least you could share the links here. And I am not using Mahout only for building an application. As I said, in some cases, I need to modify the implementations of Mahout as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fork the project on [Gihub](https://github.com/apache/mahout) into your own repository. Make the modifications you want and if they are good enough create a "pull request" back to Mahout. They may be incorporated into the mainstream.

Be aware that Mahout does not accept old style Hadoop "mapreduce" code. The new Mahout is based on more modern compute backends, mostly Spark but more recently Flink. The project is also primarily Scala although this is not a requirement.

The modern Mahout Recommender support is provided through `SimilarityAnalysis.cooccurrence` and `SimilarityAnalysis.rowsimilarity`. These provide for collaborative filtering and content-based recommendations but must be served using a knn/search engine. See Mahout docs [here](http://mahout.apache.org/users/algorithms/intro-cooccurrence-spark.html) and a full running recommender here: https://templates.prediction.io/PredictionIO/template-scala-parallel-universal-recommendation